# Calculate coordinates from velocity or orientation

Tags: matrices, orientation

I am trying to picture the car position from a game.

We can assume that the initial position is (0,0)

The API delivers velocity [x,y,z] (meters/sec) and orientation [yaw,pitch,roll] (radians).

Is it possible to calculate the next position, if I know that I retrieve this data at a fixed rate of 100ms? Can you assist me with the calculations?

**Edit** What I done so far:
x = Math.Cos(wrapper.data.Telemetry.Pitch) * Math.Cos(wrapper.data.Telemetry.Yaw);
y = Math.Cos(wrapper.data.Telemetry.Pitch) * Math.Sin(wrapper.data.Telemetry.Yaw);

vec = (x + y) * speed

But im not sure, if this is correct

**Edit 2: velocity vectors:** 
I tried working with velocity vectors, but I seem to be making something wrong.
I calculate x,y like this:

```
updateRate = 10 // every 100 ms

float vX = velocityX / updateRate;
float vY = velocityY / updateRate;

xPos = xPos + vX;
yPos = yPos + vY;
```

So what I do here is starting at (0,0), i calculate the meters traveled in each direction (vX and vY) and add this to the initial position. However this seems to be wrong, x is groving with an different rate as y - this is probably because the forward velocity is always greater than the Y velocity. It feels like I need to do more.

Comment: You can estimate the position, but you will be accumulating error. You have only a first order model of your trajectory, when the car changes orientation you will have a sample only some milliseconds after that happened, and this will mean a drift from the exact position. If in your game the velocity (and its orientation) change only by steps at your sampling instants, you can be lucky and find the correct position.

Comment: How would I have to calculate the positions even with the drift? I want to display the position of the car, it is probably ok with the drift

Comment: As you have the three components of the speed you don't need the orientation. If $P_0=(0,0)$ is your initial position, you can iterate to find $P_n=P_{n-1}+(x,y)\Delta t$, where $t=n \Delta t$ is the time at iteration $n$.

Comment: If you have the speed decomposition along the current orientation, that is usually indicated as $(v_\rho,v_\theta,v_\phi)$, you need something along what you wrote, but you need to multiply everything by $v_\rho\Delta t$

Comment: Could you explain what vρΔt is?

Comment: $\Delta t$ is your time resolution (100ms), $v_\rho$ is the speed along your heading (one of the components of your velocity vector).

Comment: Please see my last edit. Seems like i´m still missing something

Comment: Your last expression seems correct, probably you need to better understand the measurements you get. I'd like to help more, but it is hard as more information is needed about the interface with your game.